# R: Is it possible to update the timezone for all objects in a list that have POSIX-related dates

Tags: r, date, posixct, facebook-prophet

I am exploring Facebook's `prophet` package in R.  I have noticed that the package sets all dates to the `GMT` time zone with no way (that I am aware of) to set the time zone when calling the function.

My question is: given that the `prophet` algorithm returns a list of lists with several different POSIXt or POSIXct objects, is there a way to change all of these objects *at once* to the same time zone without having to change all objects individually?

For instance, if I have an object created by the `prophet` function called `prophet.model`, I can update `history.dates` or `start` from the `GMT` timezone to the `"Europe/Paris"` time zone using:

`library(prophet)`

`history <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2016-01-01'), by = 'd'),
                      y = sin(1:366/200) + rnorm(366)/10)`

`prophet.model <- prophet(history)`

`attr(prophet.model$start,"tzone") <- "Europe/Paris"`

`attr(prophet.model$history.dates,"tzone") <- "Europe/Paris"`

Can this be done instead for the whole object `prophet.model` at once without having to make individual calls to `attr`?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue?